# Find the number of solutions to the equation $\sin\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt x}4\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt {2-x}}4\right)=\sqrt 2$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, contest-math, roots

The following question appeared in a JEE Mock exam, held two days ago.

**Question:**

Find the number of solutions to the equation $\sin\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt x}4\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt {2-x}}4\right)=\sqrt 2$

**My Attempt:**

I think if each term is $\frac1{\sqrt 2}$ then it would add upto $\sqrt 2$. So, $x=1$ is a solution.

How can we tell about other solutions, if any?

Comment: Remember that both sine and cosine are periodic functions, though, in this case, you have sqrt(x) and sqrt(2-x) in the problem suggesting you only need to check values of x between 0 and 2

Comment: If calculus is allowed, you could take an appropriate derivative and check whether its sign changes.

Comment: The derivative is strictly positive, so there can only be one or zero solutions.

Comment: The derivative is clearly positive on the domain.

Comment: Yes. The implied domain is $[0,2],$ since the function is undefined elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt x}4\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt {2-x}}4\right)-\sqrt 2=0$

Check that $f'(x)>0$ in [0,2], $f(x)$ being  increasing function, it can have at most one root in the domain [0,2]. As $f(1)=0$, the single root is $x=1$

Answer (score 5):

From the comments, the domain is $[0,2]$.

Let $f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt x}4\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt {2-x}}4\right)-\sqrt 2$

$f'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt x}\frac\pi4\cos\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt x}4\right)+\frac1{2\sqrt{2-x}}\frac\pi4\sin\left(\frac\pi4\sqrt{2-x}\right)$

Angles of sine and cosine are varying from $0$ to $\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}$. That means $f'(x)\gt0$. Thus it crosses x-axis either once or never.

Also, since $f(x)$ is increasing, we only need to check values at domain end points.

$f(0)=\cos\left(\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}\right)-\sqrt2\lt0$

$f(2)=\sin\left(\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}\right)+1-\sqrt2$

$4\gt2\sqrt2\implies\frac\pi4\lt\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}\implies \sin\left(\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}\right)\gt\frac1{\sqrt2}\gt0.7$

Thus, $f(2)\gt0$

Thus, the given equation has one and only one solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = 2 \cos^2 \theta, \theta \in \left[0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$

Then we have $\sin \left(\dfrac{\pi \cos \theta}{2\sqrt 2}\right) +\cos \left(\dfrac{\pi \sin \theta}{2\sqrt 2}\right) = \sqrt 2 $

Now if $\sin \theta > \cos \theta $ we have $\cos \left(\dfrac{\pi \sin \theta}{2\sqrt 2}\right)<\cos \left(\dfrac{\pi \cos \theta}{2\sqrt 2}\right)$ and hence

LHS  $< \sin \left(\dfrac{\pi \cos \theta}{2\sqrt 2}\right)+\cos \left(\dfrac{\pi \cos \theta}{2\sqrt 2}\right)<\sqrt 2$ (by a well known result) which contradicts equality condition.

Similarly we can argue that $\sin \theta \not < \cos \theta$. Hence we have $\sin \theta = \cos \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and at which LHS=RHS.

Thus $\boxed{x=1}$ is the unique solution

Comment: Lovely solution, thanks